# Why doesn't the back button show up the second time I push the view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail

Every time I click a picture I call this method (which pushes a view on the detail view):

```
-(IBAction) loadTeamView:(id)sender {
teamView = [[TeamViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TeamViewController" bundle:nil detailItem:self.detailItem];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:teamView animated:YES];
}
```

It works but if you click the back button (which automatically comes up) and then come back to this method no back button shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider not storing the ViewController you're pushing. There's no need to store it, and it's only going to cause trouble like this.

Comment: Thank you for the response but unfortunately the back button still goes away.

Comment: You're also leaking teamview.  Put autorelease on the end of the line, unless there is a really good reason to retain this thing.

Comment: They were not deprecated. ARC is still optional. Memory management, through ARC or manual, is still integral in software development and should not be dismissed

Comment: Maybe you're doing some stuff in vewDid(will)appear.
Could you post more code ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I am using automatic memory management, also I don't have any code in vewDidAppear or willAppear or anything like that but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not changing the content of the `navigationItem` property of the view controller. As per the documentation, the navigation controller follows the following rules for the left-hand side navigation bar button:

> The bar button item on the left side of the navigation bar allows for
>   navigation back to the previous view controller on the navigation
>   stack. The navigation controller updates the left side of the
>   navigation bar as follows:
>
> 1. If the new top-level view controller has a custom left bar button
>      item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom left bar button
>      item, set the leftBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s
>      navigation item.
> 2. If the top-level view controller does not have a
>      custom left bar button item, but the navigation item of the previous
>      view controller has a valid item in its backBarButtonItem property,
>      the navigation bar displays that item.
> 3. If a custom bar button item is
>      not specified by either of the view controllers, a default back button
>      is used and its title is set to the value of the title property of the
>      previous view controller—that is, the view controller one level down
>      on the stack. (If there is only one view controller on the navigation
>      stack, no back button is displayed.)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html